# The application A sends the URL to the application B

Tags: java, android, string, url

I believe that this is correct version and do not understand why it gives error. And nothing appears in the log. When sending "url" from app to app B error appears and discontinue all.

App A button

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("url", "http://46.182.25.34:1935/tv/1420/playlist.m3u8");
intent.setPackage("ro.vrt.exo");
intent.setClassName("ro.vrt.exo", "ro.vrt.exo.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

App B  (mini player)

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String url = bundle.getString("url");

emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

//For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play.  More can be found at
//https://archive.org/details/more_animation
emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: You should post the error you get.

Comment: as two different applications emulators nothing appears only app stopped

Comment: put a try/catch around your code and display the error you catch in a toast for example.

Comment: did you setup the required properties in your manifest?

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

Comment: have added something manifest?

Comment: You should read this http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log:

> 01-14 10:50:06.687 17571-17571/ro.grupulvrt.virtualromaniatvvrt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: ro.grupulvrt.virtualromaniatvvrt, PID: 17571
>                                                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW pkg=ro.vrt.exo cmp=ro.vrt.exo/.MainActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{21765e9 17571:ro.grupulvrt.virtualromaniatvvrt/u0a62} (pid=17571, uid=10062) not exported from uid 10061
>                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2430)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
>                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
>                                                                                         at ro.grupulvrt.virtualromaniatvvrt.XXX$9.onClick(XXX.java:633)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I added android:exported="true" in the project manifest.xml , and now is work fine.